# How to SELECT * FROM table WHERE "function_value"? in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I got  one function that  call fn_distance ($a, $b, lat , lon) it  return a value to  me but  I want  to  make a select * from in my table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dados 
WHERE fn_distance ($a, $b, lat , lon) >100
```

Can someone  help me?

The true function that I found in the net was SELECT fn_distance ($a, $b, lat , lon) AS dist_km FROM dados

but it just return me a value for query

Comment: Did you try the query as written?  It should work.

Comment: Where is that function defined? Is it a  PHP function, or a user-defined function in MySQL?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Try using google`s sugestion regarding this, I have implemented and it is ok https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#maps-topnav  (query at the line with '$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( ...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following query, it will help you :

```
SELECT * FROM dados 
WHERE (select fn_distance ($a, $b, lat , lon)) >100;
```